# Python GUI: Organizing and Interacting with Displayed Text- Need help to find suitable widget/object

Tags: python, user-interface

I am quite new to Python and have been writing my first GUI with tkinker with mostly ttk widgets. I have been searching for the better part of a day to figure out how to best go about solving a problem.

My goal: To create a document that will have check boxes next to each entry that when selected to perform an action. I have all the data management figured out. The issue is that I will have a variable number of entrees each with a variable about of text. What i am trying to do is figure out which widget or other object i should use to 1st keep inserted chunks of text aligned with a particular check box and 2nd have the view be scroll-able and locate-able(IE click on words in table of contents and have it bring to view said text from long list of entrees). Would anyone happen to have any suggested library or widgets i should look into to get this working?

I have thought about using many text boxes and linking check boxes to each text box. I cannot however figure out how to make these multitude of text boxes sit in a scroll-able frame that will re-size based on content and still have coordinates to point to that will adjust the view to the proper entry when selected from a table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

A really great tutorial, which takes you through a bunch of widgets can be found here.

http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/

I went through it today, and I already have a working application with QSliders, QFrames, a graph widget and a bunch of controls.